# $I(Z(y-x^{2},z-x^{3}))=(y-x^{2},z-x^{3})$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Why is this:

$I(Z(y-x^{2},z-x^{3}))=(y-x^{2},z-x^{3})$

"obvious"?

I can easily see $Z(y-x^{2},z-x^{3}) = \lbrace (k,k^{2},k^{3}) \vert k \in\mathbb{A}^{1} \rbrace$

but I have some problems when I need to take the ideal of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(y-x^2,z-x^3)$ is a radical ideal, in fact prime ideal, because $k[x,y,z]/(y-x^2,z-x^3)=k[x]$. Now use Hilbert's Nullstellensatz. (Alternatively, a direct computation also works.)

Comment: How do you conclude that $(y-x^2,z-x^3)$ is radical? Which theorem?

Comment: 1. Prime ideals are radical. 2. $\mathfrak{p} \leq R$ prime iff $R/\mathfrak{p}$ is an integral domain.